# SQL Merge is not adding to table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to merge a temporary table, populated with data from a c# application with a table in my SQL database.

Having read through some articles it seems that SQL Merge should be the most appropriate option and it works great when I'm updating or deleting groups of entries from the database.

My problem is that I'm unable to add a new row of data where the foreign keys don't match what is already in the database table, but instead it is just removing the rows in the database and replacing the new ones in the temporary table.

I have two foreign keys referenced in the table FirstDBTableID and SecondDBTableID.

This is my SQL so far:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_UpdateTable]
@TempTable as TempTableType READONLY
AS
BEGIN    
MERGE dbo.Table AS target
USING @TempTable AS source ON target.FirstDBTableID = source.FirstDBTableID
AND target.SecondDBTableID = source.SecondDBTableID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET target.Provider = source.Provider, target.Value = source.Value,    target.Quantity = source.Quantity
-- value doesn't exist in the target table, so add it
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT (FirstDBTableID, SecondDBTableID, Provider, Value, Quantity)
    VALUES (source.FirstDBTableID, source.SecondDBTableID, source.Provider, source.Value, source.Quantity)
-- value doesn't exist in the source table, so delete from target
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN 
    DELETE;

END
```

Have a missed statement? Maybe SQL Merge isn't going to work here? If I haven't made it clear please ask me questions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can reproduce your issue. Can you please check this link and let me know if you have something similar but with different output? http://rextester.com/OODI79888

Comment: Thanks for the response, yes thats very similar however it looks like you're having the same issue as me, how about adding data from the source to the target, but also keeping the existing data in the target? Thats my issue. Is it because I'm deleting anything from the target that isn't in the source?

Comment: Is the delete necessary then? The delete is working as it should

Comment: I edited my comment above, I still need to delete data from the target if its not in the source, when providing the same "fid" with new data.

Comment: Aha! So you need to delete only if `fid` doesn't match, regardless of `sid` status?

Comment: Yes exactly, thats why I'm only merging where target and source id are matching. The rest of the data in the table should remain untouched.

Comment: But how will it be untouched if you explicitly delete it? The merge for insert and update is fine, but if you delete, it will do just that based on the condition.

Comment: Yeah I think thats my problem, I only want to delete from target, when doing the merge on fid between source and target and the data not existing in source. Mentally I see target as a chunk of data from the sql table where the fid matches that of the source id, the problem is that if its not in the source id then its not going to know whether to delete from target. So I think that may have solved my question and that what I'm trying to do isn't possible with merge.

Comment: I'm thinking now that it will be easier to delete all entries from the target table where fid matches and then insert the entries from the source. Although this will mean more processing effort, it will do the job.